# While loop that is not working with Try/Catch statements

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

Im trying to give the user the opportunity to repeat an input after introducing something that has produced an error but something is not working because once the *err* is caught the try stuff is not executed again, instead it goes directly to the catch stuff generating an eternal cicle. Here is my code:

```
while (err==1){
    err=0;
    try{
        dim = keyboard.nextInt();
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Oops! What you entered is not an integer.");
        err=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try clearing the buffer with `keyboard.nextLine()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enter a non-integer the `Scanner` call to `nextInt()` doesn't consume the non-integer. You need to call `keyboard.next()` (or `keyboard.nextLine()`) to consume it. Something like,

```
try {
    dim = keyboard.nextInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.printf("%s is not an integer.%n", keyboard.next());
    err = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! That works perfect. Anyway, I still don't know why if I'm calling "nextInt()" it returns the last input or err. I don't know how the class Scanner works but I was sure that every time you call "nextInt" it was cleaning its buffer... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Gabriel Because the error is that there isn't an `int`. You say give me an `int` and the Scanner says there isn't one (there's a `String` waiting). Then you start the loop again, and say give me an `int` and the Scanner says...

Comment: Sound good! But, when you say to the object "give me an int" you first enter some string in the console that I assume it goes directly to the objetc buffer after pressing enter... so why in my case that step doesn't exist and goes directly to ask for a int in the current buffer?

Comment: It does go directly into the `Scanner` (the object buffer)... and it doesn't leave until you read it out successfully... I have a `String`... you say give me an `int`... I say there isn't an `int`... but, there is still the `String`.

Comment: I'am wondering: if after calling the object keyword with the statement "nextInt" the buffer is not flushed then why if I call this function for example twice in a row I can get the two inputs separately without calling "next()". You know what I mean?

Comment: You aren't getting two inputs separately. Your getting the same input... let's say you input "Fred". Then you say give me an `int`, the Scanner throws an error because "Fred" isn't an `int`. Then you start the loop over, and say give me an `int`... the Scanner throws the same error because "Fred" hasn't changed into an `int`. It doesn't throw "Fred" away. And it doesn't wait for more input from the user. It says "Fred" isn't an `int`.

Comment: Yep, I think I get that part perfectly :) What I mean in the last comment was, for example: number1=keyword.nextint(); number2=keyword.nextint(); I can perfectly get the two numbers whitout having to clearing the buffer. Why?

Comment: Are you entering `int`(s)? If you say give me an `int`, and there is an `int`; the Scanner says here is your `int` and clears the buffer because it *delivered* an `int`.

Comment: Applause! I can't say I'm an expert in terms of getting inputs through Scanner but I get the important idea of: "Keep asking me but I'm not cleanin my buffer until I can give you exactly what you are looking for. Okay, if you whant me to clean it just say next and nothing happened here". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing/flushing the scanner buffer after each user input.

- Use `keyboard.nextLine()` just before the end of while loop(after the catch block)

  OR
- Declare the scanner object inside the while loop itself `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604125/how-can-i-clear-the-scanner-buffer-in-java)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the **`input.nextInt()`** command it only reads the int value. It would be even better, if you read the input through `Scanner#nextLine` and convert your input to integer using [Integer#parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method.

This does work for me.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int err = 1;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (err == 1) {
        err = 0;
        try {
            int dim = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
            System.out.println("done.. exit");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ups! What you entered is not an integer.");
            err = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
dd
Ups! What you entered is not an integer.
23
done.. exit
```

**next()** can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by space. Also, next() places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

**nextLine()** reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n). Once the input is read, nextLine() positions the cursor in the next line.

for reading the entire line you can use `nextLine()`

Comment: Thanks! It works because when the cicle starts again you call again the class Scanner. Like Elliott Frisch said I think this is more correct to use the keyboard.next() to clean the buffer.